# Using a CTE to split results across a CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have some data that I need to output as rows containing markup tags, which I'm doing inside a table valued function.

This has been working fine up to a point using code in the format below, using the `search` query to gather my data, and then inserting into my returned table using the output from `results`.

I now need to take a longer data field and split it up over a number of rows, and I'm at something of a loss as to how to achieve this.

I started with the idea that I wanted to use a CTE to process the data from my query, but I can't see a way to get the data from my `search` query into my CTE and from there into my `results` set.

I guess I can see an alternative way of doing this by creating another table valued function in the database that returns a results set if I feed it my `comment_text` column, but it seems like a waste to do it that way.

Does anyone see a route through to a solution?

Example "Real" Table:

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    comment_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    comment_title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    comment_text char(500)
);
```

Add Comment Rows:

```
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Bob', 'Example','Bob''s Comment', 'Text of Bob''s comment.');
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Alice', 'Example','Alice''s Comment', 'Text of Alice''s comment that is much longer and will need to be split over multiple rows.');
```

Format of returned results table:

```
DECLARE @return_table TABLE
(
   comment_date DATETIME,
   commenter_name VARCHAR(101),
   markup VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Naive query (Can't run because the variable `comment_text` in the SplitComment CTE can't be identified.

```
WITH SplitComment(note,start_idx) AS
(
   SELECT '<Note>'+SUBSTRING(comment_text,0,50)+'</Note>', 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '<Text>'+SUBSTRING(note,start_idx,50)+'</Text>', start_idx+50 FROM SplitComment WHERE (start_idx+50) < LEN(note)
)
INSERT INTO @return_table
SELECT results.* FROM
(
   SELECT
   comment_date,
   CAST(first_name+' '+last_name AS VARCHAR(101)) commenter,
   comment_title,
   comment_text
   FROM @Comments
) AS search
CROSS APPLY
(
           SELECT comment_date, commenter, '<title>'+comment_title+'</title>' markup
 UNION ALL SELECT comment_date, commenter, SplitComment
) AS results;

SELECT * FROM @return_table;
```

Results (when the function is run without the CTE):

```
comment_date            commenter_name                                                                                        markup
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Bob Example                                                                                           <title>Bob's Comment</title>
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Alice Example                                                                                         <title>Alice's Comment</title>
```

Ideally, I'd like to get one additional row for Bob's comment, and two rows for Alice's comment. Something like this:

```
comment_date            commenter_name   markup
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Bob Example      <title>Bob's Comment</title>
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Bob Example      <Note>Bob's Comment</Note>
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Alice Example    <title>Alice's Comment</title>
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Alice Example    <Note>Text of Alice''s comment that is much longer and w</Note>
2017-07-07 11:53:57.240 Alice Example    <Text>ill need to be split over multiple rows.</Text>
```

Comment: Got any samples of what you are putting in and what you expect to see?

Comment: If you want to generate XML/HTML from T-SQL please use FOR XML and not string concatenation.

Comment: @Bogdan_Sahlean I don't want to generate proper XML/HTML, I need to return the results in this mad format so they can be consumed by another application in use elsewhere in the business. You haven't seen anything like the worst of this function...

Comment: Do you really need to CROSS APPLY? If the date is the connection between comment and commenter - isn't it just assigning a row number in your SplitComment and inner/left join your commenter with comment and order by?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The thrust of my question is about how to get the `comment_text` variable into the SplitComment function. At the moment it simply doesn't know that `comment_text` exists and so I can't use it.

Comment: Ahh - then I think the easiest would be to simply make a user defined function and call that in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this (it' a simplified version, I used only first name and comment_date as "identifier").
I tested it using this data and - for the moment - imaging max len 50 to split text column.
Tip: change comment_text datatype to VARCHAR(500)

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    comment_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    comment_title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    comment_text VARCHAR(500)
);

    INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Bob', 'Example','Bob''s Comment', 'Text of Bob''s comment.');
    INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Alice', 'Example','Alice''s Comment'
    , 'Text of Alice''s comment that is much longer and will need to be split over multiple rows aaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc ddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffff ggggggggggggg.');

WITH CTE AS (SELECT comment_date, first_name, '<Note>'+CAST( SUBSTRING(comment_text, 1, 50) AS VARCHAR(500)) +'</Note>'comment_text, 1 AS RN
             FROM @Comments 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT A.comment_date, A.first_name, '<Text>'+CAST( SUBSTRING(A.comment_text, B.RN*50+1, 50) AS VARCHAR(500)) +'</Text>'AS comment_text, B.RN+1 AS RN
             FROM @Comments A 
             INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.comment_date=B.comment_date AND A.first_name=B.first_name 
            WHERE  LEN(A.comment_text) > B.RN*50+1                    
             )
SELECT A.comment_date, A.first_name, '<title>'+ comment_title+'</title>' AS markup  
FROM @Comments A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.comment_date, B.first_name, B.comment_text AS markup  
FROM  CTE B ;
```

Output:

```
    comment_date        first_name  markup
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Bob         <title>Bob's Comment</title>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Alice       <title>Alice's Comment</title>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Bob          <Note>Text of Bob's comment.</Note>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Alice        <Note>Text of Alice's comment that is much longer and wi</Note>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Alice        <Text>ll need to be split over multiple rows aaaaaa bbbb</Text>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Alice        <Text>bb cccccc ddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffff g</Text>
2017-07-07 14:30:51.117 Alice        <Text>gggggggggggg.</Text>
```

Comment: It's certainly a viable option to go that route, but in the real programming task I have in front of me it's going to introduce a lot of changes and overhead to do it that way. I'm asking this question to find a way to make the minimum impact on a set of existing code. Thanks though!

Comment: which kind of solution are you looking for?  It's seems to me that you looked for a CTE query

Comment: Apologies, I've been doing this for too long today and I confused myself when I tried to port your answer back to my original code. Your answer is correct, I'm just being stupid. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change Bob <Note>, it's quite easy to do it in the first row of cte using a CASE (I am not sure you want this or if it's a type error in your quest.)

Comment: Remember to change the 50's with 500 (I user 50 to simplify my testing).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that also allows sorting the resultset

It uses a recursive CTE to calculate the positions in the long text.
And by joining the table to the CTE, the text can be sliced up into rows.

```
with cte as 
(
  select id, 1 as lvl, len(comment_text) as posmax, 1 pos1, 50 limit
  from @Comments
  union all
  select id, lvl + 1, posmax, iif(pos1+limit<posmax,pos1+limit,posmax), limit
  from cte
  where pos1+limit<posmax
)
, CTE2 AS 
(
select id, 0 as lvl,
 comment_date,
 concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as commenter,
 '<Title>'+rtrim(comment_title)+'</Title>' as markup
from @Comments
union all
select t.id, c.lvl,
 comment_date,
 concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as commenter_name,
 concat(iif(lvl=1,'<Note>','<Text>'),substring(comment_text,pos1,limit),iif(lvl=1,'</Note>','</Text>')) as markup
from @Comments t 
join cte c on c.id = t.id
)
select comment_date, commenter, markup 
from CTE2
order by id, lvl;
```

Output:

```
comment_date             commenter     markup
-----------------------  ------------  -------------------------------------
2017-07-07 15:06:31.293  Bob Example   <Title>Bob's Comment</Title>
2017-07-07 15:06:31.293  Bob Example   <Note>Text of Bob's comment.</Note>
2017-07-07 15:06:31.293  Alice Example <Title>Alice's Comment</Title>
2017-07-07 15:06:31.293  Alice Example <Note>Text of Alice's comment that is much longer and wi</Note>
2017-07-07 15:06:31.293  Alice Example <Text>ll need to be split over multiple rows.</Text>
```