# t-sql - Apply function to a column without sqlFunction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, cross-apply

I've to transform a numeric code in an alphabetic code like this:

1234 -> ABCD

where 0 = 0, 1 = A, 2 = b, etc..

This is my function and how to use:

```
Create function dbo.DecodeNumToChar
(
    @change varchar(10),
    @foo varchar(10)
) returns varchar(10)
as
begin
    DECLARE @II int = 1,
            @result varchar(10)
    ;WITH x AS 
    (
        SELECT @II as ii, STUFF(@foo,@II,1,SUBSTRING(@change,CAST(SUBSTRING(@foo,@II,1) AS INT)+1,1)) AS AA
        UNION ALL
        --SELECT @II+1
        SELECT  ii+1, STUFF(AA,ii+1,1,SUBSTRING(@change,CAST(SUBSTRING(@foo,ii+1,1) AS INT)+1,1)) AS AA
        FROM x 
        where ii+1 <= LEN(@foo)
    )

    select top 1 @result = AA from x order by ii desc
    return @result
end
--------------------------------------------
select brand_code, dbo.DecodeNumToChar('0ABCDEFGHI', brand_code) 
from (VALUES('1234'),('5834'),('9905'),('0250')) as t(brand_code)
```

This function working well, but in production DB we do not have permission to create functions.

I've tryed to transform this function into CTE like this

```
declare @change varchar(9) = 'ABCDEFGHI'
DECLARE @II int = 0

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (10) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number)
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values ORDER BY Number
),
innerCTE as
(
    SELECT x.n, SUBSTRING(t.brand_code, x.n, 1) chnum, 
    case SUBSTRING(t.brand_code, x.n, 1)
        when '0' then '0'
        else char(65-1+SUBSTRING(t.brand_code, x.n, 1))
    end chalfa, t.brand_code
    FROM x INNER JOIN (VALUES('1234'),('5834'),('9905'),('0250')) as t(brand_code)
    ON x.n <= LEN(t.brand_code)
),
CTE as
(
    select n, chnum, chalfa, brand_code, stuff(brand_code, n, 1, chalfa) as code
    from innerCTE
    union all 
    select n+1, chnum, chalfa, brand_code, STUFF(code, n+1, 1, chalfa) as code
    from cte
    where n+1 <= LEN(cte.brand_code)
)
--select * from innerCTE
select * from CTE;
```

or using CROSS APPLY like this example: [Example_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968576/using-a-cte-to-split-results-across-a-cross-apply?answertab=active#tab-top)

or using CROSS APPLY with PIVOT like this example: [Example_2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199427/sql-server-create-temporary-function-as-a-cte?answertab=active#tab-top)

but my experience on SQL is low and I have not been able to get the correct result.

I'd like to have this:

```
brand_code  decoded_code
1234        ABCD
5834        EHCD
9905        II0E
0250        0BE0
```

thanks

Comment: I'd just use 10 nested `REPLACE` assuming you are not on a version that does actually have `DECODE`

Comment: Martin's tip is the easiest and straightforward.

Comment: Looks like a good time to use [CLR Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration)

Comment: @Jodrell you are definitely right but I do not know if I can on PROD environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find a solution using recursive CTE.

```
declare @change varchar(10) = '0ABCDEFGHI'
DECLARE @II int = 1;

with BRANDS as
(
    select * from (VALUES('1234'),('5834'),('9905'),('0250')) as t(brand_code)
),
CTE as
(
    select  @II as ii, BRAND_CODE, 
            STUFF(brand_code,@II,1,SUBSTRING(@change,CAST(SUBSTRING(brand_code,@II,1) AS INT)+1,1)) AS AA
    from BRANDS
    union all
    select  c.ii+1, b.BRAND_CODE, 
            STUFF(AA,c.ii+1,1,SUBSTRING(@change,CAST(SUBSTRING(AA,c.ii+1,1) AS INT)+1,1)) AS AA
    from BRANDS b
    inner join CTE c on b.BRAND_CODE = c.BRAND_CODE
    where c.ii < LEN(b.BRAND_CODE)
)

select BRAND_CODE, AA as NewCode from CTE where ii = len(brand_code) order by BRAND_CODE, ii
```

Comment: Recursion + string functions might be a performance hit if you need to convert thousands of records in one go. Try the solution with a decent amount of test values and see if it suits your requirements. Also please try Martin's suggestions, it's very simple and might be the fastest solution yet posted.

Comment: @EzLo I see... so.. In my case there are 300 records and codes with 3 digit lenght :-)

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar If this is a *one-time-action* it doesn't matter. If you need this more often and you have not more than 3-digit length, I'd think about a physical table from 0 to 999 with the codes in a second column. Generate it once and use it simply by joining it to your set...

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL 2017+

```
DECLARE @integerValues TABLE ([I] INT);

INSERT INTO @integerValues ([I])
VALUES
    (1234),
    (6485834),
    (99084705),
    (1124601);

SELECT
            T.[I],
            STRING_AGG(
                CASE SUBSTRING(T.[S], V.[number] + 1, 1)
                    WHEN '9' THEN 'I'
                    WHEN '8' THEN 'H'
                    WHEN '7' THEN 'G'
                    WHEN '6' THEN 'F'
                    WHEN '5' THEN 'E'
                    WHEN '4' THEN 'D'
                    WHEN '3' THEN 'C'
                    WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
                    WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
                    ELSE '0'
                END,
                '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.[I]) [S]
    FROM
            (SELECT [I], CAST([I] AS VARCHAR(10)) [S] FROM @integerValues) T
        JOIN
            [master]..[spt_values] V ON V.[number] < LEN(T.[S])
    WHERE
        V.[type] = 'P';
```

or, if 2016 or earlier

```
DECLARE @integerValues TABLE ([I] INT);

INSERT INTO @integerValues ([I])
VALUES
    (1234),
    (6485834),
    (99084705),
    (1124601);

SELECT
        [I],
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            CAST([I] AS VARCHAR(10)),
                                            '1',
                                            'A'),
                                        '2',
                                        'B'),
                                    '3',
                                    'C'),
                                '4',
                                'D'),
                            '5',
                            'E'),
                        '6',
                        'F'),
                    '7',
                    'G'),
                '8',
                'H'),
            '9',
            'I') [S]
    FROM
        @integerValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses a `FOR XML` subquery and some mod (`%`) operations against the integer value to split each digit, then a mapping table to relate each digit with a character. The `FOR XML` returns the digits back in order.

```
DECLARE @IntegerValues TABLE (Integer INT)

INSERT INTO @IntegerValues (Integer)
VALUES
    (1234),
    (6485834),
    (99084705),
    (1124601)

SELECT
    T.Integer,
    Conversion = (
            SELECT
                '' + M.Character -- Must have no declared alias (for xml)
            FROM
                (VALUES
                    (1, T.Integer                       % 10),
                    (2, T.Integer /  10                 % 10),
                    (3, T.Integer /  100                % 10),
                    (4, T.Integer /  1000               % 10),
                    (5, T.Integer /  10000              % 10),
                    (6, T.Integer /  100000             % 10),
                    (7, T.Integer /  1000000            % 10),
                    (8, T.Integer /  10000000           % 10),
                    (9, T.Integer /  100000000          % 10),
                    (10, T.Integer / 1000000000         % 10),
                    (11, T.Integer / 10000000000        % 10)
                ) AS X(OrdinalPosition, SplitDigit)
                INNER JOIN (VALUES
                    (0, '0'),
                    (1, 'A'),
                    (2, 'B'),
                    (3, 'C'),
                    (4, 'D'),
                    (5, 'E'),
                    (6, 'F'),
                    (7, 'G'),
                    (8, 'H'),
                    (9, 'I')
                ) AS M(Digit, Character) ON X.SplitDigit = M.Digit
            WHERE
                X.OrdinalPosition <= FLOOR(LOG10(T.Integer)) + 1 -- This expression returns the number of digits
            ORDER BY
                X.OrdinalPosition DESC
            FOR XML
                PATH('')
        )
FROM
    @IntegerValues AS T
```

Result:

```
Integer     Conversion
1234        ABCD
6485834     FDHEHCD
99084705    II0HDG0E
1124601     AABDF0A
```

There is probably a cleaner way to write the mappings and the mod operations, but this should give an idea.

Comment: Hi @EzLo, thanks for your solution, it's working. In the same time i've resolved with another query that you can read here in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the suggestion from @Martin Smith to use 10 nested replace.

```
DECLARE @change char(10) = '0ABCDEFGHI';
--------------------------------------------
select brand_code,
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( brand_code
    , '0', SUBSTRING( @change, 1, 1)) , '1', SUBSTRING( @change, 2, 1)) 
    , '2', SUBSTRING( @change, 3, 1)) , '3', SUBSTRING( @change, 4, 1)) 
    , '4', SUBSTRING( @change, 5, 1)) , '5', SUBSTRING( @change, 6, 1)) 
    , '6', SUBSTRING( @change, 7, 1)) , '7', SUBSTRING( @change, 8, 1)) 
    , '8', SUBSTRING( @change, 9, 1)) , '9', SUBSTRING( @change, 10, 1)) 
from (VALUES('1234'),('5834'),('9905'),('0250')) as t(brand_code);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: I'm using it just in case the string used to change the values is changed. If the values remain the same, I agree that the hard coded value would suffice and we can remove the SUBSTRING.